# How to Log a statement in j2me?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I developed an application in j2me, it is executing successfully. In future, if there is any issue in my statements, I want to debug my application. I know that, I can use System.out.println() but I want to log a statement, how can I do it in j2me? if possible provide me a sample code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120618/logging-in-j2me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

`public static void logToConsole(String str) {`

```
     System.out.println(str);
```

}

Declare it in your utility class and use it.

If you want to get a screen logger put your messages in it and display it on the canvas.

`//Vector which will hold your logs`

`private static Vector logData = new Vector();`

public static void logToScreen(String str) {

```
    logData.add(str);
```

}

Now use it in your canvas.

`public static Vector getLogData() {`

```
    return logData;
```

}